# Windows Server 2003 R2 Update service does not start

Tags: windows-update, wsus, windows-server-2003-r2

Windows 2k3 R2 server SP2 server running WSUS 3.0 sp2.

WSUS was working fine for almost a year. Unfortunately the update service on the server stopped auto starting about two months ago and required a manual restart. Now it will not start at all.

I get the following error:
Event Type:    Error
Event Source:    Service Control Manager
Event Category:    None
Event ID:    7009
Date:        23/02/2011
Time:        01:00:23 PM
User:        N/A
Computer:    ********** (Server Name)
Description:
Timeout (30000 milliseconds) waiting for the Update Services service to connect.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Has anyone got an answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSUS needs SQL Server to run.
My guess is that SQL Server takes some time to start and WSUS times out attempting to connect to it.
After the system start-up is completed and you manually start WSUS, SQL Server is running properly and WSUS starts successfully.

So, make sure SQL server is running properly (usually with WSUS its a local instance of SQL Express).
also in the Services.msc applet make sure there is a dependency between WSUS and SQL Server so SQL Server starts before WSUS.